# Passing value to form using JQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, parameter-passing

I've wired scenario here I've a php page which has multiple form not nested though. 
they are all hidden div's they will popup once button click. the code below is show and hide the div that will record.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ontop4 {
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #434343;
    opacity: .95;
    /*filter: alpha(opacity = 90);*/
}

#popup4 {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-color: green;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -250px;
    margin-left: -250px;
}
</style>
<form role="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post" id="form_edit_note">
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_note_case_id" value="<?php echo $findCase->id; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_note_id" value="<?php  ?>" />
    <div id="popDiv3" class="ontop4">
        <div class="row" id="popup4">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="portlet">
                    <div class="portlet-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea rows="2" cols="63" name="pic_note"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 ">
                                <div class="portlet-body form">
                                    <div class="form-body pull-right">
                                        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn yellow btn-xs add_case_note_cls" id="close"> Cancel </a>
                                        <input type="submit" name="saveAttach" id="saveAttach" value="Save" class="btn yellow btn-xs">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

the data i need to edit is displaying in my main form which is a simple php while loop. what i want to know how to set the below variable

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden_note_id" value="<?php  ?>" />
```

I would like to have this `hidden_note_id` value set dynamically i mean passing through on click edit on one of them notes to transfer note_id through ajax, jQuery or which ever way. Please help

I may not have conveyed my message properly but I'll make it simple that on my main page there are multiple notes are displayed user can edit any note but the form above is outside the scope of that form so how would I get the note id that user has decided to edit .

any idea?